# start timer when window load

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code below which is a forward timer, when I press **start** it starts counting in hh/mm/ss, and when I press **Display time taken** it shows time taken in hh/mm/ss inside the  tag, and resets the counter to zero on button click and starts counting from zero.

My problem is that the timer initially only starts when I press the **start** button.

I want to make the timer start automatically when the window loads and remove the start button.

How can be this be achieved?

```js
window.onload = () => {
  let hour = 0;
  let minute = 0;
  let seconds = 0;
  let totalSeconds = 0;

  let intervalId = null;

  function startTimer() {
    ++totalSeconds;
    hour = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
    minute = Math.floor((totalSeconds - hour * 3600) / 60);
    seconds = totalSeconds - (hour * 3600 + minute * 60);

    document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = hour;
    document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = minute;
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
  }

  document.getElementById('start-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    intervalId = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);
  })

  document.getElementById('Displplaytimetaken').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById("timetaken").innerHTML = minute + "minutes" + seconds + "seconds";
    reset();
  });

  function reset() {
    totalSeconds = 0;
    document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = '0';
    document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = '0';
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = '0';
  }

}
```

```html
<h1 style="font-size:24px;">Time Taken:
  <h1 id="timetaken"></h1>

  <button id="start-btn">Start</button>
  <button id="Displplaytimetaken">Display time taken</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
window.onload = () => {
  let hour = 0;
  let minute = 0;
  let seconds = 0;
  let totalSeconds = 0;

  let intervalId = null;

intervalId = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);
  function startTimer() {
    ++totalSeconds;
    hour = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
    minute = Math.floor((totalSeconds - hour * 3600) / 60);
    seconds = totalSeconds - (hour * 3600 + minute * 60);

    document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = hour;
    document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = minute;
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
  }

  

  document.getElementById('Displplaytimetaken').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById("timetaken").innerHTML = minute + "minutes" + seconds + "seconds";
    reset();
  });

  function reset() {
    totalSeconds = 0;
    document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = '0';
    document.getElementById("minute").innerHTML = '0';
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = '0';
  }

}
```

```html
<h1 style="font-size:24px;">Time Taken:
  <h1 id="timetaken">

  </h1>

  <h2>    <span id="hour"></span>
    <span id="minute"></span>
    <span id="seconds"></span>
  </h2>

  <button id="Displplaytimetaken">Display time taken</button>
```

Run it and hope your problem get solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<body onload="startTimer()">
```

In your HTML.

Does that help?